# Excel error at the second instance

Tags: excel, runtime-error, vba

I hope someone can help me figure this out. I don't know what's wrong, but my program is giving me an error stating:

```
Run-Time error '1004':

Application-defined or object-defined error
```

Which point to this line of code:

```
lr.Range(1, 1).Value = Date
```

My program works for the first instance, (first time you will run it.) and then throw this error if you repeat the process. Please help! I've been stuck here for a week.

Here's the complete code which is placed on a command button. Basically what the code does is record several details that the user inputted from a different userform.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim lo As ListObject
Dim lr As ListRow
Dim X As String


Set ws1 = Sheets("ACCOUNTS")
Set ws = Sheets("OB RECORDS")


ws1.Activate
ws1.Range("B1").Select

Do Until ActiveCell.Value = Me.TextBox1.Text
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
If IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value) Then
MsgBox "No Time-In Found", vbCritical
Me.TextBox1.Text = ""
Me.TextBox1.SetFocus
Exit Sub
End If
Loop

ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Select
X = ActiveCell.Value
ws.Activate
ws.Range("E6").Select

Do Until X = Me.txtcont.Text 'txtcont value is being populated at a different form (frmpass.txtcont.Text = Me.cmbstaff.Text)

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

If IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value) Then

MsgBox "No account matches this password. Please try again.", vbCritical
Me.TextBox1.Text = ""
Me.TextBox1.SetFocus
Exit Do
Exit Sub

End If
Loop

Range("I" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Select
If IsEmpty(ActiveCell) Then

MsgBox "Unable to Time-Out this time because you still have an unclosed O.B filed." & vbNewLine & "Please Time-In and close first.", vbCritical

Unload Me
frmOB.Show

Exit Sub
End If

Set lo = ws.ListObjects(1)
Set lr = lo.ListRows.Add

ws.Unprotect "321321"

lr.Range(1, 1).Value = Date 'this is where the error is and I don't know why
lr.Range(1, 2).Value = frmout.TextBox1.Text
lr.Range(1, 3).Value = UCase(frmout.cmbstaff.Text)
lr.Range(1, 4).Value = UCase(frmout.TextBox2.Text)
lr.Range(1, 5).Value = UCase(frmout.TextBox3.Text)
lr.Range(1, 5).Value = UCase(frmout.TextBox3.Text)
lr.Range(1, 6).Value = Time
lr.Range(1, 6).NumberFormat = "h:mm:ss AM/PM"
lr.Range(1, 8).Value = UCase(frmout.TextBox4.Text)
ActiveWorkbook.Save
MsgBox "O.B log successfully recorded. Take care!", vbInformation
ws.Protect "321321"

Unload Me

frmOB.Show

Exit Sub

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: Probably unrelated to your error, but the `Exit Sub` immediately following an `Exit Do` will never be evaluated, which means that after displaying `"No account matches this password."` your code is continuing on.

Comment: Didn't work much with list objects. Will changing `lr.Range(1, 1)` to `lr.Columns(1)` fix it? Since it is single row anyway it should return only one cell.

Answer (score 0):

In your following code you try to add a listrow in a protected sheet:

```
Set lo = ws.ListObjects(1)
Set lr = lo.ListRows.Add

ws.Unprotect "321321"
```

So your add method doesnt work and lr is nothing. When you try to usee `lr.range` excel throws an error.

Just put the unprotect before you add the new line:

```
ws.Unprotect "321321"

Set lo = ws.ListObjects(1)
Set lr = lo.ListRows.Add
```